# Random freezes during work (Fusion Drive not removed correctly?)

Tags: ssd, performance, fusion-drive, hdd

I have a Macbook Pro 13" late 2011 and ever since I've replaced DVD-reader for an SSD my notebook started freezing sometimes. It happens suddenly, for no reason whatsoever and I can only move mouse cursor during the freeze. I've put my old HDD into a tray in place of the DVD-reader and I used to think that the tray was working badly. A couple hours back I placed the DVD-reader back and it turns out that no, the HDD wasn't the reason. I've checked SMART status of my SSD, though – it should not cause any problems as well. Oh, and I've checked the console – there are no error messages during the freeze (well, except for a 'log write error' from one small program, but I doubt this is the reason). What else should I check?

UPD. I have used TRIMEnabler's benchmark to test my SSD and it shows the picture [image: SSD Picture]

That's weird, isn't it? I have experimented with creating Fusion Drive when I just got my SSD – may the reason for hang-ups be the incorrectly split-up Fusion Drive? How can I check for traces of FD, by the way?

Comment: do you have a console log for us around the time stamp of the event ?

Comment: I'll add one as soon as this happens the next time

Comment: What OS X version are you using?

Comment: @n1000, 10.10.4